# How to Hide elements on HTML when data comes NULL using React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How can I hide with for example "d-none" or similar when the data comes null. I'm working with React.

```
 <span className="product__tag">{prod.tag1}</span>
 <span className="product__tag">{prod.tag2}</span>
 <span className="product__tag">{prod.tag3}</span>
```

Comment: `span:empty{display:none;}` might work if there is no space inside your empty elements.

Comment: yes ! thanks, If you mind to answer I can check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can via CSS use the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) selector:

```
span:empty{display:none;}
```

Mind the [specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the selector if `span` `display` is elsewhere reset.

Answer (score 2):

You can try
`{prod.tag1 && <span className="product__tag">{prod.tag1}</span>}`

Answer (score 1):

**Inline Styles**

A good way to do this is with inline styles. You can check if your data is null, and display: none based on that.

```
const checkData = data == null ? "none" : "block"

...

<span style={{display: checkData}} className="product__tag">{prod.tag1}</span>
<span style={{display: checkData}} className="product__tag">{prod.tag2}</span>
<span style={{display: checkData}} className="product__tag">{prod.tag3}</span>
```

**Change the class**

This is a similar solution to the last. Instead of changing the style directly, you can change the class and then change the style based on that. This is probably more neat, and better for a larger scale.

```
const checkData = data == null ? "product__tag__hide" : "product__tag"
        
...
        
<span className={checkData}>{prod.tag1}</span>
<span className={checkData}>{prod.tag2}</span>
<span className={checkData}>{prod.tag3}</span>

... 
css

.product__tag__hide{
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:-**

```
 <span className="product__tag" style={{display: (prod.tag1 ? 'block':'none')}}>
   {prod.tag1}
 </span>
```

**Method 2:-**

```
 {prod.tag1 && <span className="product__tag">{prod.tag1}</span>}
```

**Method 3:-**

```
{prod.tag1 ? <span className="product__tag">{prod.tag1}</span>: null}
```